# Fontspec: Select minionpro font from local folder

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I have the Minionpro Font files in the same directory as the master LaTeX file. 
When compiling, the path to the MinionPro fonts folder would be `../minion/` containing:

```
./MinionPro-Bold.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCapt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCn.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnCapt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnDisp.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnIt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-BoldCnSubh.otf
./MinionPro-BoldDisp.otf
./MinionPro-BoldIt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-BoldItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-BoldItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-BoldSubh.otf
./MinionPro-Capt.otf
./MinionPro-Cn.otf
./MinionPro-CnCapt.otf
./MinionPro-CnDisp.otf
./MinionPro-CnIt.otf
./MinionPro-CnItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-CnItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-CnItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-CnSubh.otf
./MinionPro-Disp.otf
./MinionPro-It.otf
./MinionPro-ItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-ItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-ItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-Medium.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCapt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCn.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnCapt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnDisp.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnIt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-MediumCnSubh.otf
./MinionPro-MediumDisp.otf
./MinionPro-MediumIt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-MediumItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-MediumItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-MediumSubh.otf
./MinionPro-Regular.otf
./MinionPro-Semibold.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCapt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCn.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnCapt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnDisp.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnIt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldCnSubh.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldIt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldItCapt.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldItDisp.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldItSubh.otf
./MinionPro-SemiboldSubh.otf
./MinionPro-Subh.otf
```

Now I am asking myself, how to use the MinionPro font in a LaTeX document compiled with `lualatex`?
I have tried the following:

```
\setmainfont[ Path = ../minion/,Mapping=tex-text]{MinionPro-Medium}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Path = ../minion/]{MinionPro-Medium}
```

but the Math parts look horrible and contain characters not from minion pro. The big integral sign is not used etc.. 
I have been able to use the local fonts folder successfully with pdflatex ([How can I distribute a non-CTAN font with my source files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125868/how-can-i-distribute-a-non-ctan-font-with-my-source-files)).

Now to the central question: Are all the above listed `.otf` files complementary?
How to use this font? I want to use it for math mode as well as for text mode. I prefer the medium version of the font, as the thickness is perfectly for my taste. Which file contains the math bits?
Please note: I don't want to install the `.otf` in the system as I want to have them in the directory where I have them right now.

I know that are many beginner questions but I am really stuck on this task. I would be happy if someone could guide me on how to use MinionPro, having it in my local folder.

Comment: I believe the font you need for math is [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html). See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27999/10102) for details.

Comment: I could use MnSymbol, as this seems to complement the missing Symbols, but I don't know how to use MnSymbol with luatex. 
          \setmathfont{MnSymbol}
 gives me errors and produces no output :

!LuaTeX error (file /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/mns
ymbol/MnSymbol-Bold10.otf): Invalid character.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{mnsymbol}`?

Comment: Yeah, no success (If I use `\usepackage{mnsymbol}` together with `\setmathfont{MnSymbol}`). When I only use `\usepackage{mnsymbol}` the symbols are from mnsymbol but the letters etc. are still computer modern.

Comment: I believe you need `\setmainsfont{Minion Pro}` for the main font, and `\usepackage{mnsymbol}` for the symbols. Read the manual / instructions of `mnsymbol`.